# Updating text with JavaScript and Firebase

Tags: javascript, performance, html5, firebase

My problem is this causes more lag as time goes on. I use this commonly to chat with my friends, and I need it the site to update in real-time whenever a message gets edited/deleted/added. Any solutions?

```
function update(){
    var i = 0;
    var leadsRef = firebase.database().ref(room);
    leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var old_room = room;
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            if(i === 0){
                document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = "";
            }
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += encode(childData.datee);
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += "      ";
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += encode(childData.namee);
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += ": ";
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += encode(childData.contentss);
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += "<br>";
            i += 1
        }); i = 0; return 0;
    });
}
window.setInterval(update, 100);
```

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/MilkyWay90.github.io/blob/master/chat.html).

Comment: What do you mean by _"I need it to be real-time."_?

Comment: @guest271314 As in the site should update in real-time when somebody types in a message

Comment: Have you tried using a `<form>` element, and either `change` of `input` event attached to a `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">` element, or an `<input type="submit">` for the user to press when they want to send a message? Am not certain about why `setInterval` is being used, though should be able to be substituted for `requestAnimationFrame` and logic within the function body. Does the code at the question currently produce the expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 Not sure hwo to do that, could you put the complete code in an answer?

Comment: Have not tried Firebase. Why does `update` need to be called every `100` milliseconds to re-declare `leadsRef` and reattach `value` event to `leadsRef` variable?

Comment: @guest271314 I am not sure how to change the text only when the database has changed.

Comment: What triggers `value` event attached to `leadsRef` to be dispatched?

Comment: @guest271314 Can you automatically move this discussion to chat? It's not letting me saying you're suspended from chatting. I dont know when it is dispatched

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Can you list the properties of `childData`? Does it have more than just `datee`, `namee`, and `contentss`? Such as an `id` or something?

Comment: @202_accepted No. I made a link to the full code which tell you the answer

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Am banned from chat at SE sites as the message you got states. It appears that you need to first understand what your own code does before asking how to improve your code.

Comment: @guest271314 Oh. So should I delete the question because I need to know what my code does before asking?

Comment: @guest271314 or should I ask on StackOverflow pretty quickly and just come back hee with the answer?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 That would be a practical first step. You could ask on SO, though you would still be in the position of clearly not knowing what your own code is doing, nor precisely what the expected result is.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Any and all code relevant to the problem should be embedded in the question, linking off-site is not permitted, as described in the help-center: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Additionally, you should fully understand what the code does, and it sounds like you may not, though I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you do.

Comment: Additionally, the root of your problem is the `+=` and constant reloading of _all_ messages, you need to find a way to track what the "last" message was and only load "new" messages, that will be the first step towards success.

Comment: @202_accepted Got it! I think that should be my answer, so can you put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Leaking

Between:

```
window.setInterval(update, 100);
```

And:

```
leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {...}
```

You are adding a new copy of the event handler every 100ms. which just stacks the handle so it runs (time elapsed since page load)/100ms times every time data hits the pipe.

Setting your on('value') handler should fire every time firebase get new data. It's a watcher you've got here not a getter.

## 2. Redundant Look ups

```
document.getElementById("comments")
```

This can be held in a variable and reused rather than finding the element for every stub of text.

## 3. innerHTML

Setting innerHTML from user input is considered bad practice, use innerText instead. Also build you full string(if possible) and and update all at once, this limits the browser having to re-render the page

## 4. Data / Output Structure

Each message is an individual item and should be treated as such, showing all the messages into a single p element muddies the distinction and make addressing an individual item difficult if desired

## Other/Misc

You should be able to replace the provided code with somthing like this (warning untested, also assumes comments is a div not a p as in the linked code):

```
firebase.database().ref(room).on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var comments = [];
    var commentParent = document.getElementById("comments")
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var commentElm = document.createElement("div");
        commentElm.setAttribute("class", "comment")
        commentElm.innerText = encode(childData.datee) + "      " + encode(childData.namee) + ": " + encode(childData.contentss);
        comments.push(commentElm)
    });
    commentParent.innerHTML=''
    commentParent.append(...comments)
    return 0;
});
```

Also there is an additional bug with room handling, when changing rooms the handler should be removed and recreated for the new room.

And your linked code pollutes all over the global space >.> not as important since it's not a shared lib but it still rubs me the wrong way.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/plloi/fc37pmqa/

Comment: Keeps on outputting "[object HTMLDivElement],"

Comment: Missed a spread operator, updated

Comment: Okay, let me test it

Comment: Okay, that issue is resolved, but now it keeps on outputting the entire script every second

Comment: Like if it said "MW90: hi", it would keep on outputting "MW90: hi" every second. Wait, that just can be fixed by setting document.getElementById("comments") to []

Comment: Squashed a bug, added a link to jsfiddle, slightly less untested.